# Using passwords from kwallet in i3

Tags: ubuntu, kde-plasma, i3

I recently installed the i3 window manager on my kubuntu system.

When I log in to i3, network manager will not automatically connect to wifi, as it doesn't have access to the passwords.

I can run `kwalletmanager` and open the settings window. Here I can open the wallet. But when I try to run `kwalletd` I get the following error:

```
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
kwalletd(6836): Communication problem with  "kwalletd" , it probably crashed. 
Error message was:  "org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownInterface" : " "No such interface 'org.kde.KUniqueApplication' at object path '/MainApplication'" "
```

I haven't been able to find information about how to start `kwalletd` outside the kde desktop, or find much information about how the the desktop does versus the system.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you've already set up sddm for opening your kwallet, I propose such option:

1. Install `libpam-kwallet-common` (KWallet integration with PAM)
2. Add this to your i3 config

```
    exec --no-startup-id /usr/share/libpam-kwallet-common/pam_kwallet_init
```

The path can vary between distros.On Gentoo it's `/lib64/libexec/pam_kwallet_init`.
That will automatically launch kwallet and try to open it with the same password you use to log in.
If you don't know what I'm talking about, take a look at this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KDE_Wallet#Unlock_KDE_Wallet_automatically_on_login

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to get round my problem:

In the wifi settings, `wifi security` I can choose to make to `Store password for all users (not encrypted)` which then lets me access the connection from i3, although I still have to activate the connection.

It works but it's not quite optimal for me, so I'm still open to other ideas :)